# JSF Templating with russian

Tags: templates, jsf, character-encoding, facelets

I have the following template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>
        <ui:insert name="title" />
    </title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="header">Some header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Some Footer</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and the following client template:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        English Online
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>Кириллический шрифт</h1>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Now the problem is:

When I invoke the master template from the composite with the Cyrillic font in "h1"-tag, the browswer gives out:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Even though I use the Cyrillic font in the master-client template it is ok. And when the client template h1-tag contains English it also works.
How can I fight this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if those files are not saved as UTF-8. The answer depends on the editor used to save the files. If it's for example Eclipse (your question history hints that you're using it or are at least familiar with it), then you need to change *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding* to UTF-8.

[image]

After making this change, edit and re-save the file(s).

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)